# How to insert variables in JavaScript strings?

Tags: javascript, string

What's the best way to do insert variables in a string in JavaScript? I'm guessing it's not this:

```
var coordinates = "x: " + x + ", y: " + y;
```

In Java, `String`s are immutable and doing something like the above would unnecessarily create and throw away `String`s. Ruby is similar and has a nice way of doing the above:

```
coordinates = "x: #{x}, y: #{y}"
```

Does something similar exist for JavaScript?

Comment: Strings are immutable in JavaScript as well. The plus (concatenation) operator makes a new string from pieces of an old one.

Comment: Are we strictly talking vanilla here? Anyway underscores' templates do a pretty good job at that

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript equivalent to printf/string.format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610406/javascript-equivalent-to-printf-string-format)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Introduced in ES6 as "template strings"

MDN docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

```
const name = "Nick"
const greeting = `Hello ${name}`  // "Hello Nick"
```

Comment: Template strings were part of ES6 and that standard came around, and was implemented by browsers, well after 2013 when I posted this question. Nevertheless, you're correct and I will award you the check :)

Comment: Any particular reason here for using back-ticks?  Will single quotes work?

Comment: No, You need to use backticks. It is how echmascript (javascript) knows how to inject variables into `${}` locations. A single tick would just signify a normal string and would be interpreted as such.

Answer (score 3):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/stringinject

https://github.com/tjcafferkey/stringinject

I created this function to do exactly this, it will allow you to pass in a string, and an object with keys that will replace placeholder values in the string with their values like below:

```
var str = stringInject("My username is {username} on {platform}", { username: "tjcafferkey", platform: "GitHub" });

// My username is tjcafferkey on Github
```

Comment: Pretty sure you accidentally transposed the variables. The way you have it written, I would expect it to set str to be "My username is Github on tjcafferkey"

Comment: Great spot. Got them the wrong way round on my example.

Answer (score 2):

That's fine in JavaScript.  There is no good built-in equivalent of an `sprintf` or `String.format`, however, [you can build your own](https://stackoverflow.com/q/610406/143295).

Don't worry about the "unnecessary" string objects.  That's definitely micro-optimization.  Address it if and when you need that extra tiny bit of performance or memory optimization, but in distributed software, you probably don't.

Comment: Plus, if it is really common performance problem I would expect JS implementations to have it optimized. I know Java compiler does such optimization.

Answer (score 1):

If for some reason you are doing this many times per second and referencing the strings many times per call, you can always store *the strings themselves* as variables.

```
var preX = 'x: '
  , preY = 'y: '
  , coords
  ;
coords = preX + x + preY + y;
```

This of course should be supported by benchmarking/profiling, but creating many strings per frame is often a source of unnecessary garbage which can result in jank down the line.

Comment: Is there really a JS interpreter that won't inline all of the raw strings? I feel like this might be *slower* on some browsers, since now the engines have to examine the `preX` (etc.) variables which could have changed, whereas it is impossible to change a string literal.

Comment: Agreed, I'd expect it to be slower. However, my case was specific to referring to the same string literal hundreds of times per frame (say in a visualization with many dynamically labeled points). The speed hit of optimized lookup (which will just be indexing into a given offset) will *likely* not outweigh string creation time for each literal. I imagine you are correct that the literals are optimized to some degree, but that varies browser by browser, making  code that relies on that behavior implementation dependent.