# Get variable to use inside JavaScript string to collect API data

Tags: javascript, template-literals

I'm trying to connect to an API. By doing this with a static string, it works fine, but when I'm doing it by using a variable, it seems not to work.

This is how my code looks:

```
var movie = 'taken';

OurRequest.open('GET', 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=${movie}&apikey=222222');
OurRequest.onload = function() {
  console.log(OurRequest.responseText);
};
OurRequest.send();
```

So when I remove `${movie}` and replace it with `'taken'` as a string, it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not every browser supports JavaScript Template literals. You can concatenate the value like this:

```
OurRequest.open('GET', 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=' + movie + '&apikey=222222');
```

If you really want to use JavaScript Template literals, then you need to enclose the entire string in back ticks, not the usual single or double quotes. Like this:

```
OurRequest.open('GET', `http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=${movie}&apikey=222222`);
```

Comment: Why did you answer work and not mine?
I read an answer in this thread:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19105009/how-to-insert-variables-in-javascript-strings

Comment: @PhilipCarlsson see my answer for this question

Answer (score 0):

You should use backquote "`" to interpolate your variable inside your string. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals