# Use curl with a variable

Tags: javascript

I would like to know if it is possible to use curl with a variable. This is the code I am using:

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;
function execute(command, callback) {
  var a = exec('curl -F data=@/"doc.xml" https://chowlk.linkeddata.es/api', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    callback(stdout);
  });
};
execute('ping -c 4 0.0.0.0', (a) => {
  download("a.owl", a);
});
```

The code works, but where it says doc.xml I want to put a variable where I have previously saved the xml. I have tried different ways but I have not succeeded. Is it possible to pass a variable to curl?

Comment: This is not about passing a variable to curl at all. It is about inserting a string into another string. curl doesn't matter here. Also, the code you have is invalid, you cannot wrap something in double quotes inside a double quoted string.

Comment: `exec("curl -F data=@/\"" + yourvariable + "\" https…")` or ``exec(`curl -F data=@/"${yourvariable}" https…`)`` (make sure you control the source of the variable's value, otherwise: hello command injection)

Comment: Duplicate [How to insert variables in JavaScript strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19105009/how-to-insert-variables-in-javascript-strings)

Comment: Also note that your code is completely broken. There's no download function to be seen, and the ping string is just discarded, since the execute function isn't using the `command` parameter anywhere.

Comment: The code as currently presented has a syntax error. `exec("curl data=@/"doc.xml" https…")` is invalid syntax

Comment: Just curious. Using HTTPS. Why using curl and not using ajax?